# Objective C - SKEmitterNode position range

Tags: position, range, sprite-kit, skemitternode

Question is how to define a non-rectangular shape for emitter node position range?

By position range I mean this:

```
emitter.particlePositionRange = CGVectorMake(50,75);
```

Is there some workaround to make this area triangular instead of rectangular?

Comment: nope, at best you can use multiple emitters with smaller ranges

Comment: So am I missing the point here, or this kind of 'problem'  is allways solved in this way (with multiple emitters creating aproximate shape) ? Thank you.

Comment: always like that, non-rectangular-shape-based emitters aren't very common actually